# Duplicate one webhook to two web servers?

Tags: node.js, networking, proxy, webhooks

I am working on a NodeJS project, that accept webhooks from number of resources (GitHub, Google Drive, etc')

While developing I want to get the webhook to my dev machine.
At the same time I want the same webhooks to go to my server.

I don't want to register new webhooks, and remove them during each build.
I want to keep the webhook, and during a dev runtime, to be able to get the webhooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have developed it, since I didn't found something similar to this.
I believe it can help some other developers.

https://github.com/AminaG/replicate-proxy

Example of settings.json file:

```
[
{
    "ip":"127.0.0.5",
    "log":"mylog1.json",
    "webhooks":[
        {
            "url":"http://requestb.in/1fdvicp1",
            "log":"mylog2.json"
        },
        {
            "url":"http://httpbin.org/post",
            "log":"mylog4.json",
            "master":true
        },
        {
            "url":"https://ek0fcy1x0jjm.runscope.net/abc?d",
            "log":"mylog2.json"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

- Split the webhook to many server if it is needed.
- We save the request, and let us to repeat it.
- We save all the request, and when we need to repeat we can specify the server
- If there is master, we reply with master response!